# Mageton 1.8 Can't save config

Tags: magento

**Hello**
I have problem on magento Ver 1.8 error after click "save config" will show this

---

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/www/virtual/infone.co.th/htdocs/lib/ip_files/49.php' (include_path='/home/www/virtual/infone.co.th/htdocs/app/code/local:/home/www/virtual/infone.co.th/htdocs/app/code/community:/home/www/virtual/infone.co.th/htdocs/app/code/core:/home/www/virtual/infone.co.th/htdocs/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/www/virtual/infone.co.th/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php on line 130

---

How can i fix it?

thanks you.

Comment: Does this help at all? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111470/fatal-error-require-once-failed-opening-required-d-xampp-htdocs-magento-er

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP, the programming language that Magento's implemented in, is trying to load the file

```
/home/www/virtual/infone.co.th/htdocs/lib/ip_files/49.php
```

from your web server.  This is not something a stock Magento system does.  It appears your system's been modified such that this stock Magento file

```
/home/www/virtual/infone.co.th/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php
```

is trying to load this `lib/ip_files/49.php` file.  This may have been done by a previous developer of your system, or this may have been done by people trying to compromise your Magento systems's security.  Without seeing the code in `ConfigController.php` that's trying to load this file it's impossible to say.  Someone must have removed this file from your system.

You could probably make this specific error go away by uploading a `49.php` file to the specific path, but if this file doesn't do what your previous `49.php` file did there may be further problems.